# Simple jQuery and PHP login issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello I am trying to implement a simple login feature using jQuery and PHP however the login keeps failing and I cannot figure out why.

This is the PHP function that deals with the login

```
function login()
{
    $return = array(
        'success' => false
    );

    if ($users[$_POST['login']] == $_POST['password']) {
        $return = array(
            'success' => true
        );
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    }

    print(json_encode($return));
}
```

The username is declared in a different PHP file and is declared like so.

```
$users['admin'] = '123654';
```

The following jQuery code should do the loging in.

```
$(self).on('click', '.loginSubmitButton', function() {

        var username = $('#username').val().trim();
        var password = $('#password').val().trim();


        $.post(settings.server, {
            login: username,
            password: password
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
            } 
            else {
                alert('Wrong username or password!')
            }


        });

});
```

So far it doesnt implement anything in case of success because everytime I try to run this code and I enter the login credentials I get the `Wrong username or password!` alert.

Comment: Probably because `$users` doesn't exist in the scope of `function login()`

Comment: Set error reporting in PHP and see if you are receiving any errors. You will know whatever the reason for failing...

Comment: Can you confirm the output of `console.log(data)` inside your success callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the following changes to two sections:

PHP - add $users to function() like function($users) or add global as so:

```
function login()
{
    global $users;
    $return = array(
        'success' => false
    );

    if ($users[$_POST['login']] == $_POST['password']) {
        $return = array(
            'success' => true
        );
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    }

    print(json_encode($return));
}
```

jQuery - As you are returning a JSON encoded string you need to parse it into jQuery:

```
$(self).on('click', '.loginSubmitButton', function() {

        var username = $('#username').val().trim();
        var password = $('#password').val().trim();


        $.post(settings.server, {
            login: username,
            password: password
        }, function(data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.success == true) {
            } 
            else {
                alert('Wrong username or password!')
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm...I suspected i should have added the global variable, but had no idea I have to parse the data in jQuery.

Comment: Your welcome :) glad it helped, when you do json_encode you are converting the array into an encoded string, so on jQuery you need to parse it in order to bring it back into a javascript based array.